# Nan loss during training

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a custom Tensorflow estimator with the following code and running into `Nan Loss during training error`

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/mnt/release/scripts/gcloudml/projections_learning/trainer-x.x.x/trainer/task.py", line 212, in <module>
    learn_runner.run(generate_experiment_fn(**arguments), job_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 209, in run
    return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 46, in _execute_schedule
    return task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 502, in train_and_evaluate
    self.train(delay_secs=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 280, in train
    hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 677, in _call_train
    monitors=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 296, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 458, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1010, in _train_model
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([model_fn_ops.train_op, model_fn_ops.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 518, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 862, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 818, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 980, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 551, in after_run
    raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

I am following the sample code from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/estimator/trainer/model.py with the modification of using custom estimator instead of the DNNLinearCombinedClassifier.

Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

P.S.: I'm able to train with DNNLinearCombinedClassifier on my data without any issues.

Model fn:

```python
  def build_estimator(self, model_dir, hidden_units):
    def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
      input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features=features,

      feature_columns=params['feature_columns'])
      hidden_layer_units = params['hidden_layers']
      net = tf.layers.dense(input_layer, hidden_layer_units[0], 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
      for num_hidden_units in hidden_layer_units[1:]:
        net = tf.layers.dense(net, num_hidden_units, 
                              activation=tf.nn.relu)
      output_layer = tf.layers.dense(net, 1)

      # Reshape output layer to 1-dim Tensor to return predictions
      predictions = tf.reshape(output_layer, [-1])

      # Calculate loss using mean squared error
      loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, output_layer)

      # Calculate root mean squared error as additional eval metric
      eval_metric_ops = {
        "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(
          tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions)
      }

      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
        learning_rate=params["learning_rate"])
      train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

      # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.EVAL` and `ModeKeys.TRAIN` modes.
      '''
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op)
      '''
      return ModelFnOps(mode=mode,
                        loss=loss,
                        train_op=train_op,
                        predictions=predictions)


    model_params = {"learning_rate": 0.01,
                    "hidden_layers": hidden_units,
                    "feature_columns": feature_columns}
    return tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=model_params, model_dir=model_dir)
```